# Laravel nested resource controller policies

Tags: laravel

Given I have the following routes, controllers and models. How can I create **two separate** policies for the CompanyAddressController show method and the UserAddressController show method?

E.g.

- User A may have permission to view the company address & users address.
- User B may only view the company address.
- User C may view neither.

I believe it's correct to handle these via a Policy, but I'm unsure how this will work with nested resource controllers.

## Routes

```
Route::resource('company', CompanyController::class);
Route::resource('company.address', CompanyAddressController::class);
Route::resource('users.address', UsersAddressController::class);
```

## Controllers

```
// Company Controller
class CompanyController
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->authorizeResource(Company::class);
    }
}

// User Controller
class UserController
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->authorizeResource(User::class);
    }
}

// Company Address Controller
class CompanyAddressController {
    public function show(Request $request, Company $company, Address $address)
    {
        //
    }
}

// User Address Controller
class UserAddressController {

    public function show(Request $request, User $user, Address $address)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

## Models

```
// Company Model
class Company extends Model
{
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
    }
}

// User Model
class User extends Model
{
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
    }
}

// Address Model
class Address extends Model
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a policy for the address where you can put your logic to authorize based on user or company.

```
class AddressPolicy {
    public function view($user, $address)
    {
        if ($address->addressable instanceof App\Models\User) {
            // check if user can view user address
        }

        if ($address->addressable instanceof App\Models\Company) {
            // check if user can view company address
        }
    }
}
```